# SQL Select Query for Retrieving WooCommerce Order Items and Meta Data

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm working on creating some SQL Views for my Wordpress database to more easily view online orders generated via the WooCommerce plugin. I'm familiar with the WooCommerce structure and where the data is stored but being an SQL novice I'm getting stuck at the last hurdle.

I've been able to create the first view of all the order details using this reference:

http://codecharismatic.com/sql-script-to-get-all-woocommerce-orders-including-metadata/

Now I need to create a similar view of the line items for each of these orders. There are 2 tables that store order item details:

wp_woocommerce_order_items
wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta

I've been able to create the basic list of records from the wp_woocommerce_order_items table as follows:

```
SELECT order_item_id,order_item_name,order_item_type,order_id
FROM ocm_woocommerce_order_items 
ORDER BY order_id
```

This returns a nice list of records like this:

```
order_item_id   order_item_name order_item_type order_id
 2  Widgets line_item   9
 3  Widgets line_item   10
 4  Widgets line_item   11
 5  Woo Logo    line_item   473
 6  Woo Logo    line_item   473
```

I would now like to add additional columns for each line item from the wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta table. This table contains multiple records for each line item like this:

```
 meta_id    order_item_id   meta_key    meta_value
 136    16  _qty    4
 137    16  _tax_class  
 138    16  _product_id 87
 139    16  _variation_id   0
 140    16  _line_subtotal  36
 141    16  _line_total 36
 142    16  _line_subtotal_tax  3.6
 143    16  _line_tax   3.6
```

I would like to convert each of these into a new column so my output would consist of:

```
 order_item_id, order_item_name, order_item_type, order_id, qty, tax_class, product_id, variation_id, line_subtotal, line_total, line_subtotal_tax, line_tax
```

I'm not sure which SQL syntax to use here - I've tried to use a similar syntax to the link above but haven't been able to get it to work so far and not sure if that is indeed the correct syntax.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I managed to work this out by trial and error. Here's the query that worked in the end:

```
select
p.order_id,
p.order_item_id,
p.order_item_name,
p.order_item_type,
max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_product_id' and p.order_item_id = pm.order_item_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as productID,
max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_qty' and p.order_item_id = pm.order_item_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as Qty,
max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_variation_id' and p.order_item_id = pm.order_item_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as variationID,
max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_line_total' and p.order_item_id = pm.order_item_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as lineTotal,
max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_line_subtotal_tax' and p.order_item_id = pm.order_item_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as subTotalTax,
max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_line_tax' and p.order_item_id = pm.order_item_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as Tax,
max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_tax_class' and p.order_item_id = pm.order_item_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as taxClass,
max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_line_subtotal' and p.order_item_id = pm.order_item_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as subtotal
from
ocm_woocommerce_order_items as p,
ocm_woocommerce_order_itemmeta as pm
 where order_item_type = 'line_item' and
 p.order_item_id = pm.order_item_id
 group by
p.order_item_id
```

Comment: Thanks. how get `customer_id` field with top fields?

Comment: You'll need to query the Order itself which will include the customer_id for each order, so you'll be querying the `wp_posts` table directly for this

Comment: quantity coming in empty :/

Comment: In every `max` the `p.order_item_id = pm.order_item_id` condition seems unnecessary because this condition is already on `p` and `pm` in the `where` clause.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this query to get all completed orders including all metadata.

```
SELECT
        p.ID as order_id,
        p.post_date,
        max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_billing_email' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as billing_email,
        max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_billing_first_name' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as _billing_first_name,
        max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_billing_last_name' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as _billing_last_name,
        max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_billing_address_1' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as _billing_address_1,
        max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_billing_address_2' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as _billing_address_2,
        max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_billing_city' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as _billing_city,
        max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_billing_state' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as _billing_state,
        max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_billing_postcode' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as _billing_postcode,
        max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_shipping_first_name' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as _shipping_first_name,
        max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_shipping_last_name' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as _shipping_last_name,
        max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_shipping_address_1' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as _shipping_address_1,
        max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_shipping_address_2' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as _shipping_address_2,
        max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_shipping_city' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as _shipping_city,
        max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_shipping_state' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as _shipping_state,
        max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_shipping_postcode' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as _shipping_postcode,
        max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_order_total' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as order_total,
        max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_order_tax' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as order_tax,
        max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_paid_date' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as paid_date,
        ( select group_concat( order_item_name separator '|' ) from wp_woocommerce_order_items where order_id = p.ID ) as order_items
    FROM
        wp_posts p 
        join wp_postmeta pm on p.ID = pm.post_id
        join wp_woocommerce_order_items oi on p.ID = oi.order_id
    WHERE
        post_type = 'shop_order' and
        post_date BETWEEN '2021-07-01' AND '2021-08-01' and
        post_status = 'wc-completed'
    group by
        p.ID
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing - have been fiddling with this for some time now to get products for orders currently being processed!

Comment: Really like this query. I've been joining over and over to wp_postmeta for each attribute and that works and all (so big FROM clause instead of big SELECT clause), but this in some ways is simpler. Preesh

Answer (score 0):

@mostafa Norzade I don't have commenting previlige so posting as answer

the meta_key for user_id is '_customer_user', so simply add the following:
max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_customer_user ' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as customer_user,

Comment: it doesn't work.. can you rewrite the full query?